# Is there a way to get the variable name dynamically based on table name here?

Tags: python, if-statement, dynamic

This code is very self-explanatory, and I just know there has to be a better way. I hope the title is clear enough to understand what I'm trying to do here.

```
    if self.table == 'BodyPart':
        working_keys = BodyPart_Keys
    elif self.table == 'IncidentEvent':
        working_keys = IncidentEvent_Keys
    elif self.table == 'InjuryType':
        working_keys = InjuryType_Keys
    elif self.table == 'ObservationType':
        working_keys = ObservationType_Keys
    elif self.table == 'TaskStatus':
        working_keys = TaskStatus_Keys
    elif self.table == 'AuditInspection':
        working_keys = AuditInspection_Keys
```

Comment: you shouldn't have the different keys in different variables, instead you should have a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I like to use a mapping with a Python `dict` object. The main benefit I think is that lookup is `0(1)` so it should be about as efficient as a nested `if` condition.

Example:

```py
fn_1 = lambda: 'hi, im function 1'
fn_2 = lambda: 'hello from function 2'

my_mapping = {'A': fn_1,
              'B': fn_2}

working_keys = my_mapping[self.table]

print(working_keys())
```

Comment: ended up using this as more keys got added to the if...elif...elif chain. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is adding a trailing `_Keys` to the table name.
This can be done by simply writing `working_keys = self.table + '_Keys'`.

If the variables are inside some module you can access the specific variable as `module.__dict__[working_keys]`.

If you want an additional check to see whether the table name is only from a selective set of names you can do:

```py
permitted_names = {'BodyPart', 'IncidentEvent', ...} # create a set
if self.table in permitted_name:
    do_something()
```

You need to clarify more details about the variable names, and where they're coming from.

Comment: thank you for the answer, ended up using a dict of variables to choose instead as more keys got added to the list. couldn't really share more detail as this is a corporate project and I don't want to divulge any more than necessary. thanks though.